# async task doesn't work in 'Scheduled Tasks' of plesk

Tags: c#, iis, asynchronous, plesk, telegram

I've created an .exe file and uploaded to my host. I Add Task in Scheduled Tasks in plesk panel of my host. My Code running successfully completed but some part of my code(async task) didn't run.
here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)        {
        Console.WriteLine("Started in "+DateTime.Now.ToString());

        new Task(GetTime).Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static async void GetTime()
    {
        string x= await DoWork();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }


    private static Task<string> DoWork()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return DateTime.Now.ToString()+ " Done.";
        });
    }
```

It works fine in my pc:

> Started in 6/4/2017 1:06:01 PM
>
> 6/4/2017 1:06:04 PM Done.

but in host only first WriteLine works:

> Started in 6/4/2017 1:06:01 PM

Comment: Wait for the task to complete. I dont even know why you are starting a task; it's not like you are doing other things while that task is going on.

Comment: I have to wait  for bot.GetMessages();

Comment: Not sure that issue in async code, I've using Golang programs with a lot of async goroutines in Scheduled Tasks without issues. Pay attention that you executing your program in another environment(OS, network, env vars etc). I've suggest to create pure C# program without any third-party libs which doing something async.

Comment: I've created another simple async program and uploaded it to my host. but didn't work.